# How to use shortcite in apacite?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite, cite-package

I am using `apacite` package as mentioned in my MWE. However, it does not seems to recognise `\shortcite` command (see the attached figure - the citation is not green as in `cite`). is there a way to resolve this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[]{apacite}
\begin{document}
\title{some text}

Smith et al. \shortcite{TestCite} some text.
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

**sample.bib**

```
@article{TestCite,
    Author = {Smith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J and Yang, X. and Silva, E.},
    Journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
    Title = {A title},
    Volume = {3},
    Year = {2000}}
```

[image]
I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: The MWE compiles without error for me and produces a citation that I would be ready to believe is a short citation. What *exactly* do you mean by "it does not seems to recognise \shortcite command"? Are you talking about your editor and its syntax highlighting or about LaTeX throwing real errors? If you are talking about LaTeX errors, please show us the relevant part of the `.log` file. If you are talking about your editor, please tell us what editor you use and include a screenshot of the problematic bit.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the comment. However, I get the results of `\cite{}` for `\shortcite{}`. I am expecting only the year as the results of `shortcite`

Comment: If I understand the documentation of `apacite` correctly, `\shortcite` is not mean to display only the year. It is meant to switch between the full and shortened list of authors. Are you looking for `\citeyear`? Given that you write `Smith et al. \shortcite{TestCite}` I have a hunch that what you are really looking for is `\shortciteA{TestCite}`.

Comment: @moewe thanks a lot. using `citeyear` solved my issue. thank you once again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the `apacite` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) the normal `\cite` command follows the APA rules that are as follows (see also 
https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/11/the-proper-use-of-et-al-in-apa-style.html)

- Name lists with one or two names are always shown in full.
- Name lists with three to five names are shown in full on a first citation and are abbreviated to the first name and "et al." on subsequent citations.
- Name lists with six or more names are always shortened to first name + "et al.".

If there is a choice between the long and a short form in citations, the command `\shortcite` always gives you the abridged list of names in citations, `\fullcite` always gives the long list of names.

So

```
\shortcite{TestCite}
```

is expected to give

> (Smith et al., 2005)

Hence the MWE works as expected.

---

In the comments it emerged that you only want to print the year of the citation. That can be done with `\citeyear`. But your use case

```
Smith et al. \shortcite{TestCite} some text.
```

makes me think that

```
\shortciteA{TestCite} some text.
```

or

```
\citeA{TestCite} some text.
```

would be the cleaner solution.

---

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage[]{apacite}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{five,
  author  = {Smith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J. and Yang, X. and Silva, E.},
  journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
  title   = {A title},
  volume  = {5},
  year    = {2005},
}
@article{three,
  author  = {Zmith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J.},
  journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
  title   = {A title},
  volume  = {3},
  year    = {2003},
}
@article{seven,
  author  = {Bmith, R. and Jones, O. and Doe, J. and Yang, X. and Silva, E. and William Write and James Hacker},
  journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
  title   = {A title},
  volume  = {7},
  year    = {2007},
}
@article{two,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby and Annie Hacker},
  journal = {A Great Predatory Journal},
  title   = {A title},
  volume  = {2},
  year    = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\shortciteA{five} some text.

\citeA{five} some text.

Smith et al.\ \citeyear{five} some text.


\cite{two} -- \cite{two} -- \shortcite{two} -- \fullcite{two} -- \citeyear{two}

\cite{three} -- \cite{three} -- \shortcite{three} -- \fullcite{three} -- \citeyear{three}

\cite{five} -- \cite{five} -- \shortcite{five} -- \fullcite{five} -- \citeyear{five}

\cite{seven} -- \cite{seven} -- \shortcite{seven} -- \fullcite{seven} -- \citeyear{seven}


\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith et al. (2005) some text.//Smith et al. (2005) some text.//Smith et al. (2005) some text.//(Appleby & Hacker, 2002) – (Appleby & Hacker, 2002) – (Appleby & Hacker, 2002) – (Appleby & Hacker, 2002) – (2002)//(Zmith, Jones, & Doe, 2003) – (Zmith et al., 2003) – (Zmith et al., 2003) – (Zmith, Jones, & Doe, 2003) – (2003)//(Smith et al., 2005) – (Smith et al., 2005) – (Smith et al., 2005) – (Smith, Jones, Doe, Yang, & Silva, 2005) – (2005)//(Bmith et al., 2007) – (Bmith et al., 2007) – (Bmith et al., 2007) – (Bmith et al., 2007) – (2007)]

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer. This is very helpful :)